# Add App_Start folder to ASP.NET Application (Empty Template)

Tags: asp.net

So I have a asp web application (I chose empty template) and I'm trying to add the `App_Start` folder but I can find it, the option doesn't come up when I try to add an `ASP.NET Folder`. Any other way to do this than start all over again?

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure there is one. Check (or add) the Global.asax *file* for a place to add code on app start.